# How can I get rid of this line? Or atleast format it?

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-5

I must be missing something very small. I have an html table with Bootstrap5 css. I can't get the formatting right. How can I get rid of this black line or format it and the black text to make it to be less bold?

[Table Header Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzATL.png)

Here's the table header code:

```
<table id="submissionTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-6 text-center">Item Description</th>
                <th class="col-3 text-center">Quantity Used</th>
                <th class="col-2 text-center">Sold</th>
                <th class="col-1 text-center"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I'm using bootstrap.min.js and my own custom.js right below it in my `<head>`.

Here's my custom css

```
tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr {
border-style: none;
```

}

Comment: Create a code snippet for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't replicate the black line in the photo, but to change the text weight and style you can do this:

```
thead th {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

It is probably better to give the headings their own class and refer to it in the CSS like this:

```
<th class="col-1 text-center itemtitle">Item Description</th>


.itemtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect on the fonts. Still got the black line though. I'll keep plugging away on it.

Answer (score 1):

It was in my attempt to add the snippet, which I found the answer. Snippet only allows 30000 lines of text, so I was reducing what was actually needed it the bootstrap.css and by process of elimination it ended being this line:

```
.table > :not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 2px solid currentColor
}
```

Changed it to this and now the line is gone

```
.table > :not(:first-child) {
    border-top: none
}
```